# MTW Box 4.1 Contraction of EM 2-form with surface element bivector to give "magnetic flux". What does that mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

This is my attempt to make sense of Box 4.1-4.b of MTW's Gravitation. I'm not entirely sure I have the computation correct. But, even if it is correct, I
don't really understand how the final result represents a "magnetic
flux." Is this supposed to be the same thing as the familiar 3-space
version of magnetic flux through a surface? If not, then what does
"magnetic flux" mean in this context?

This is supposed to be an example illustrating the power of differential forms:

> Contraction of **Faraday** 2-form with bivector $\delta\mathscr{P}\wedge\Delta\mathscr{P}$ [where
>   $\delta\mathscr{P}=\left(d\mathscr{P}/d\lambda_{1}\right)\Delta\lambda_{1}$
>   and $\Delta\mathscr{P}=\left(d\mathscr{P}/d\lambda_{2}\right)\Delta\lambda_{2}$
>   are two infinitesimal vectors in a 2-surface $\mathscr{P}\left[\lambda_{1},\lambda_{1}\right],$
>   and the bivector represents the surface element they span] is the
>   magnetic flux $\phi=\left\langle \mathfrak{F},\Delta\mathscr{P}\wedge\delta\mathscr{P}\right\rangle $
>   through that surface element.

The **Faraday** 2-form is

$$
\mathfrak{F}=\left\{ F_{\alpha\beta}\right\} =\begin{bmatrix}0 & -E^{1} & -E^{2} & -E^{3}\\
E^{1} & 0 & B^{3} & -B^{2}\\
E^{2} & -B^{3} & 0 & B^{1}\\
E^{3} & B^{2} & -B^{1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The surface element bivector is

$$
\Delta\mathfrak{x}\wedge\delta\mathfrak{x}=\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\mu}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\nu}\Delta x^{\mu}\delta x^{\nu}=\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\mu}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{\nu}\frac{1}{2}\left(\Delta x^{\mu}\delta x^{\nu}-\Delta x^{\nu}\delta x^{\mu}\right)
$$
$$
=\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{0}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\left(\Delta x^{0}\delta x^{1}-\Delta x^{1}\delta x^{0}\right)+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{0}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\left(\Delta x^{0}\delta x^{2}-\Delta x^{2}\delta x^{0}\right)+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{0}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\left(\Delta x^{0}\delta x^{3}-\Delta x^{3}\delta x^{0}\right)
$$

$$
+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\left(\Delta x^{1}\delta x^{2}-\Delta x^{2}\delta x^{1}\right)+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{1}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\left(\Delta x^{1}\delta x^{3}-\Delta x^{3}\delta x^{1}\right)+\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{2}\wedge\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{3}\left(\Delta x^{2}\delta x^{3}-\Delta x^{3}\delta x^{2}\right),
$$

where the factor of $1/2$ doesn't appear in the last expression because only the increasing index orderings were included. Contracting this result with $\mathfrak{F}$ requires a factor of $1/2$ on the left-hand side because each of
the $E^{i}$ and $B^{j}$ come in twice. So, after permuting indices
to make the minus signs go away we have

$$
\frac{\phi}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left\langle \mathfrak{F},\Delta\mathfrak{x}\wedge\delta\mathfrak{x}\right\rangle 
$$
$$
=E^{1}\left(\Delta x^{1}\delta x^{0}-\Delta x^{0}\delta x^{1}\right)+E^{2}\left(\Delta x^{2}\delta x^{0}-\Delta x^{0}\delta x^{2}\right)+E^{3}\left(\Delta x^{3}\delta x^{0}-\Delta x^{0}\delta x^{3}\right)
$$

$$
+B^{1}\left(\Delta x^{2}\delta x^{3}-\Delta x^{3}\delta x^{2}\right)+B^{2}\left(\Delta x^{3}\delta x^{1}-\Delta x^{1}\delta x^{3}\right)+B^{3}\left(\Delta x^{1}\delta x^{2}-\Delta x^{2}\delta x^{1}\right).
$$

Writing the surface element as an anti-symmetric tensor

$$
\mathfrak{S}\equiv\left\{ S^{\mu\nu}\right\} =\left\{ \frac{1}{2}\left(\Delta x^{\mu}\delta x^{\nu}-\Delta x^{\nu}\delta x^{\mu}\right)\right\} ,
$$

requires a factor of $4$ in the expression for $\phi$ because the
components of both tensors enter twice

$$
\phi=\left\langle \mathfrak{F},\Delta\mathfrak{x}\wedge\delta\mathfrak{x}\right\rangle =\left\langle \mathfrak{F},\mathfrak{S}\right\rangle =4\left(E^{1}S^{10}+E^{2}S^{20}+E^{3}S^{30}+B^{1}S^{23}+B^{2}S^{31}+B^{3}S^{12}\right).
$$

We may also write $\phi$ in the bad-old tensor form 
$$
\phi=S^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}.
$$

But, as I say, even if I have the symbol manipulation correct, I don't understand the result.  Will someone please explain this to me?

Image added, *ex post facto* to facilitate understanding of the accepted answer. It is from MTW Box 15.1-B.

[image]

Adding second image showing a 2-surface element in $\mathbb{E}^3$ projected onto coordinate planes.  The general 2-surface may be considered to be a linear combination of the projections.  Motivated by Fig 5.21, page 329 of Edwards's *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables*.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $E^i \, dS^{i 0} \equiv \boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\ell}} \, dt$ (integrated on a small loop in 3D space) is equivalent as the e.m.f integrated on a small time interval.  From Lenz-Faraday law:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathscr{E} = \oint_{\mathcal{C}} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\ell}} = -\, \frac{d \Phi_{B}}{dt},
\end{equation}
$E^i \, dS^{i 0} \equiv \boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\ell}} \, dt$ is the magnetic flux $-\, d\Phi_{B} = -\, \boldsymbol{\mathrm{B}} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}}$ throught the small $\mathcal{C}$ loop.

The other part is also a magnetic flux through a *spacelike* surface:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
B^1 \, dS^{23} + B^2 \, dS^{31} + B^3 \, dS^{12} \equiv \boldsymbol{\mathrm{B}} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}} = d\Phi_B.
\end{equation}
Adding these two contributions gives $\phi = 0$.  So when you integrate the faraday tensor (an *exact* 2-form: $\boldsymbol{F} = \boldsymbol{dA}$) on a *closed surface* in spacetime, the total flux is just $0$.

If the spacelike surface is open, then $\phi \ne 0$ and represents the magnetic flux through the surface (in that case, just use the proper frame of the surface so $dS^{i 0} = 0$, and you get $d\phi = d\Phi_B$).

If you integrate the dual tensor ${}^*\boldsymbol{F}$ (this 2-form is not *exact*!) on a closed spacelike surface, you get the electric charge enclosed in that surface, by Maxwell's equations (Gauss theorem in its relativistic version).

Comment: I'm still thinking about this.  While considering your answer, it occurred to me that considering special cases in which the surface lies parallel to some pair of axis should be helpful in understanding this result.  Once I saw your answer, the first part was "obvious".  Less obvious is the idea that the surface may or may not be open in $X\times{Y}\times{Z}$ space.  But I will keep thinking about it.

Comment: Depending on the surface you use (open or closed in 4D spacetime), you may get several results: $\phi \ne 0$ or $\phi = 0$.  In all cases, it will give a magnetic flux if you take into account the Lenz-Faraday law (i.e Maxwell's equations).

Comment: Are you talking about the single differential surface element, or the entire surface formed by integrating over (Riemann summing) contiguous differential surface elements?  It seems to me that a differential 2-surface element will always be open.

Comment: The whole surface may be made of several pieces joined in 4D spacetime.  It could be closed or open, depending on how you join the pieces.  A closed surface in spacetime may be hard to visualise.  Just limit yourself to squares and cubes, and draw three axes: $x$, $y$ and $t$.

Comment: I have not worked it all out, but I believe a bounded unit 4-cube is just the life of a unit space-like 3-cube over a unit of time.

Comment: Don't confuse 2D surfaces in 4D spacetime with 3D hypersurfaces in the same 4D spacetime, they're not the same objects.

Comment: I will continue to think about this in terms of the two images I added to my original question.  If I have another question I will post it separately.  Thanks for the guidance.